# How to utilize regex in autocomplete JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex

Right now, I have a function that takes a json_encoded PHP array as a JavaScript object called "obj". For each keyup action by the user as they type in an input box, it triggers a function that trims the input, inserts each individual letter into an array, then a for loop concatenates a combination of regex characters that will be matched to values in obj.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var obj = <?php echo json_encode($dname_list); ?>;
        $("#input").keyup(function(){
            var input_untrimmed = document.getElementById('input').value;
            var input_trimmed = input_untrimmed.trim();
            var obj_length = obj.length;
            for(y=0;y<obj_length;y++){
                document.getElementById(y).innerHTML = ' ';   
                }
            var foundit = [];
            var num_letters = input_trimmed.replace(/[^A-Z]/gi, "").length;
            var letters = [];
            for(q=0;q<num_letters;q++){
                letters.push("(?=.*");
                letters.push(input_trimmed.charAt(q));
                letters.push(")");
                }
            letters.push(".*");
            var letters_joined = letters.join("");
            alert(letters_joined);
            for(x=0;x<obj_length;x++){
                /*if(obj[x].indexOf(input) > -1){
                    foundit.push(obj[x]);
                }*/
                if(obj[x].match(letters_joined)){
                    foundit.push(obj[x]);
                }
            }
            var foundit_length = foundit.length;
            for(y=0;y<foundit_length;y++){
                document.getElementById(y).innerHTML = foundit[y];
            }
            foundit = [];
            letters = [];
        });});
```

For autocomplete functionality, is my syntax accurate? (catching any combination of letter(s) as the user types)

Comment: Can you provide some example of what your code does ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MattS No, the OP says: _For autocomplete functionality, is my syntax accurate?_ so he is asking us to test/debug his code. CodeReview is for improving code that is known to work.